# Combine between JWT Authentication and LDAP with Symfony 4

Tags: ldap, symfony4

I want to authenticate with JWT & LDAP verification. I want a "login_check" method to check the username & password. Here are my security.yaml & services.yaml files. I can't seem to verify with LDAP and recover the token.

security.yaml

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\Users:
        algorithm: argon2i
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
            search_dn: "dc=example,dc=com"
            search_password: password
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: uid
            
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    registration:
        pattern: ^/api/users
        anonymous: true
        stateless: true
        methods: [POST]
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
              

    refresh:
        pattern: ^/api/token/refresh
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator 
    main:
        anonymous: lazy
        provider: my_ldap
        form_login_ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: 'dc=example,dc=com'
            query_string: '(&(uid={username})(memberOf=cn=users,ou=Services,dc=example,dc=com))'
```

services.yaml

```
....
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
    arguments:
        -   host: ldap.forumsys.com
            port: 389
            options:
                protocol_version: 3
                referrals: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in your case and I just get success with this, first be sure your connection with the Active directory is OK, you can test with many dumps in **Symfony\Component\Ldap\Security\LdapUserProvider** and if its OK here, you can check authentication process in **Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\LdapBindAuthenticationProvider**.

Here is my settings in security.yml file :

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: '%env(resolve:BASE_DN)%'
            search_dn: '%env(resolve:SEARCH_DN)%'
            search_password: '%env(resolve:LDAP_PASSWORD)%'
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: userPrincipalName
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        #provider: my_ldap
        json_login_ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: '{username}'
            check_path: /api/login
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false
    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        anonymous: true
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```